# Compare two random variables and their probability with respect to same number

Tags: probability, random-variables

### Problem

Given random variables $X$, $Y$, if I know $X\geq Y$, what can I say about 
$\Pr[X\geq a]$ and $\Pr[Y\geq a]$ where $a\geq 0$.

### What I Have Done

$\Pr[X\geq a]$ and $\Pr[Y\geq a]$ could be evaluated with integral but since I do not know the pdf of $X$ and $Y$,this approach could not give me
any result.

Comment: I think you can establish an inequality between the two probabilities. Note that the event $Y\geq a$ implies $X \geq a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$
Y\geq a\implies X\geq Y\geq a
$$
whence
$$
(Y\ge a)\subseteq(X\geq a)
$$
and so by monotonicicity of measure (namely, $A\subseteq B\implies P(A)\leq P(B)$) we have that
$$
P(Y\geq a)\leq P(X\ge a)
$$

Comment: Thank you for your help! But does it generally hold that if $A\Rightarrow B$, then $A\subseteq B$ and therefore $\Pr[A]\leq \Pr[B]$.

Comment: Yes. If $A\subseteq B$, then since $B=A\cup (B\setminus A)$ (which is a disjoint union), it follows that $P(B)=P(A)+P(B\setminus A)\geq P(A)$.